# how to calculate nth root of large and long number in android programmatically?

Tags: java, math

I am developing a simple android app and trying to get `nth` root of a large and long number programmatically.
I have searched many links here , but I haven't found a correct solution in android.

How can I get `nth` root of large number in android programmatically?

Comment: Are you looking for `Math.pow(x, 1.0/n)`?  By the way, this has nothing to do with Android.  Whatever Java solution there is to your problem will be valid regardless of where it's run.

Comment: yes, but i mean that x is big integer for example, 100001232101001010120320. so I can't use this function. Can you help me with any idea? In fact, I have no rich experience in android.

Comment: Once again, this is a Java question--please don't ask about a "solution in android" or talk about "experience in android".  There's nothing Android-specific about this question.  As for the answer--I tried Googling "algorithm find root BigInteger" and ran across http://bigintegers.blogspot.com/2013/07/nth-root-power.html.  Maybe that will help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. so you are telling me that in android it is impossible. Right?

Comment: NO, NO, NO.  Please read carefully!  Your problem is solvable in Java.  And if it's solvable in Java, it's solvable in Android, because Android uses Java.  And the solution would be the same on Android as on any other system that uses Java.

Comment: @ajb next time edit this question and remove the tag yourself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `bitLength` to compute the number of bits of your number. If the bit length is *k*, then your number *x* is 2<sup>*k*-1</sup> ≤ x < 2<sup>*k*</sup>. So 2<sup>⌈*k*/*n*⌉</sup> will be a reasonable upper bound for your *n*-th root. Hence your solution will have no more than *m* = ⌈*k*/*n*⌉ bits (or `m = (k - 1)/n + 1` in integer arithmetic).

Now iterate over each of these *m* bits, starting with the bit of highest value (position *m*-1 and value 2<sup>*m-1*</sup>). For each bit, decide whether it has to be set or not. Which means take the number you had before (initially zero), set the bit at the given position. Compute the *n*-th power of that (using the `BigInteger.pow` method, or perhaps using [repeated squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) if someone reading this is using a different big integer implementation). If the result is bigger than your input *x*, then clear the bit again, otherwise, leave the bit set. Continue to the next bit, until you either found an exact match or have decided on the last bit and thus found the floor of the actual non-integer root.

I don't say that this algorithm is optimal, but it should be feasible for many applications, and reasonably easy to understand and implement as well.

Here is some [working code](http://ideone.com/yTyk6M):

```
BigInteger root(int n, BigInteger x) {
    BigInteger y = BigInteger.ZERO;
    for (int m = (x.bitLength() - 1)/n; m >= 0; --m) {
        BigInteger z = y.setBit(m);
        int cmp = z.pow(n).compareTo(x);
        if (cmp == 0) return z; // found exact root
        if (cmp < 0) y = z;     // keep bit set
    }
    return y; // return floor of exact root
}
```